# iOS TKCalendarMonthView is it possible to show dates only from Monday to Friday

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar, tapku

Is it possible to show dates only from Monday to Friday in iOS TKCalendarMonthView? Like the following image

[image: TKCalendarMonthView]